# Java Application running in Docker container unable to read file in network shared location

Tags: java, file, networking, docker-compose

My java application so far running on server which is reading a data file from the shared network location and importing data successfully to db.  we are now moving this application to Docker. The step at File read operation in code is not considering a valid File location.
Java is using File f = new File("//fileserver/shared") the next step f.exists() returning null when this code is running in container. non-docker environment has no issues at this step in the past.
**Docker-compose**

```
version: '3'
services:
    app-batch:
        dns: xx:xx:x:x
        container_name: app-batch
        hostname: apphost
        build:
            context: ./app-batch
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: app-batch:1.0
        ports:
            - 8989:8989
        networks:
            - app-network
        volumes:
            - ./logs:/logs:rw

networks:
    app-network:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    logs:
```

**Dockerfile** in /app-batch folder

```
FROM openjdk:17-alpine

COPY ./*.jar myapp.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/myap.jar"]
```

tried with volume in docker-compose named as appvolume and
volumes:

```
  appvolume:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: cifs
      o:sec=ntlm,vers=3.0
      device: "//fileserver/shared"
```

but keep seeing error like not able to reach host.

The Java program in the app.jar reads network file contents as
File f =new File("//fileserver/shared/loadfile.txt");
and is not considering the File f as a file.

Q. is it possible to connect to remote server from a docker container running on a application network on a host?
if not by default possible, can you please suggest how to achieve this ?
Q. is it possible to map/bind remote path to volume ?

Comment: You haven't included a [mcve] of the failing program.

Comment: edited with some more steps, compose and docker files are same, what information can I add ?

Comment: There's no actual program in the question.  We can't solve programming problems without a [mcve] of the failing program.  (If your problem is with the runtime environment - e.g. your Docker container - then Stack Overflow is probably not the right place to find help).

Answer (score 0):

The problem resolved correcting the docker-compose volume as below..
once again, the mail issue here is docker container unable to access the network file, mapping the volume and accessing the file as local, solved the problem.
appvolume:
driver_opts:
type: cifs
device: "//myserver.com/share"
o: addr=myserver.com,username=fileuser,password=mypwd

Thanks